# Trying to Consolidate Two Water Lines + Tie In a Softener

Tags: plumbing, water-softener

I'm trying to determine the best way to simplify a mess I've inherited.  I've included an extremely rudimentary (and not to scale) sketch for reference.  If you're wondering how it arrived at this state, I'd be more than happy to explain, but for now I'm trying to keep it simple.

Basically, coming from the well are two main lines - one is 1.5" black poly and the other is 1" PEX.  The poly line is the original line that went straight to the utility room, then branches off to all of the various terminations, including the toilets.   At some point in the past, the separate PEX line was brought off the main and used to supply only the toilets; the toilets were disconnected from their original supplies, but all of the plumbing was left intact.  On this separate toilet line is a filter/softener set up.

What I would like to do is put everything back on one line, have that run through the softener, and reconnect the toilets to their original plumbing.  I was hoping I could either cut out the 1" PEX line altogether and add the softener to the poly line in the well house (Option #1 below), or tie the 1" PEX into the poly line in the crawlspace (Option #2 below).

My questions are these:

1. Will either of these work?
2. Which one would be best?
3. If the softener can be added into the poly line, what would be the best way to do this fitting-wise?
4. Is there anything I'm missing or do you have an alternative?

Thank you in advance for any help.  I have some basic know-how, but I just wanted some advice on this before I get into trouble.

Regards,
Nate

[image]

Comment: If you're asking about fittings, you'll need to provide pictures of the things in question. As it stands, the only answer we can give you is "use the appropriate ones". ;) Otherwise, excellent job on your first post!

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase.  I'm not so much worried about the exact fittings, but rather the effects on pressure and/or volume from switching between the 1.5" and 1" lines.  Would it make more sense to put the right fittings on the filter+softener and run the 1.5" right up to it, or should I just come back a little bit and reduce into the 1" and then expand back to the 1.5" after the filter+softener?  If I do come back, how far?  Or would it be better to do Option #2 and just tie in down the line?  Will either of these have a negative impact on pressure or volume or would it not matter at all?

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to join the 1" PEX line to the 1.5" pipe as in option #2. If material,time, etc. are equal option #1 seems the better choice.